# __init__.py in current working directory

Tags: python-2.7

I have a directory structure

```
log_dedupe
├── dedupe
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── sha_dedupe.py
│   ├── sha_dedupe.pyc
│   └── test_sha_dedupe.pyc
├── globals.py
├── globals.pyc
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.pyc
├── log_dedupe_main.py
├── log_dedupe_main.pyc
```

in `log_dedupe_main.py`

```
from log_dedupe import parse_arguments
```

results in

```
ImportError: No module named log_dedupe
```

If I added a `setup.py` and install a package than I don't get this error anymore. But if I change something in **init**.py than I have to reinstall.

**NOTE** I also considered importing from `__init__` in my files but I wasn't sure if that was a good idea or not.

Having just wasted a good hour of my time I find myself wondering if there's a way to either

1. override the current working directory to use the directory name rather than ''
2. automagically install a python package if a file has been changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to the directory `log_dedupe/` is in and invoke `log_dedupe_main.py` as follows:

```
python -m log_dedupe.log_dedupe_main`
```

Or better yet, rename `log_dedupe_main.py` to `__main__.py` and invoke it as follows:

```
python -m log_dedupe
```